# ThreeJS: Does bumpMap for Phong Material uses UV Mapping?

Tags: three.js, phong, bump-mapping

I got crazy trying bumpMap working on a PhongMaterial in ThreeJS (r61). The diffuse and normal are working fine. Here is my code:

```
var params = { 
    map: new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("models/displ/"+configObj.name+"_diffuse.jpg"),
    bumpMap: new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("models/displ/"+configObj.name+"_heights.jpg"),
    bumpScale: 1,
    normalMap: new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("models/displ/"+configObj.name+"_normal.jpg"),
    shininess: 45.0
};
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( params );
```

I tried modifiing bumpScale to any extreme, getting no change at all.

Does the bump map uses the loaded uv map of my object by default? I could only find example using primitive geometries like planes or spheres.

What does the UVMapping property of the texture object is good for?

Any hint appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Don't use a normal map and and a bump map at the same time and re-ask your question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint WestLangley, it worked as you said.